# React Context and Typescript

Tags: reactjs

I'am trying to create a context, this is the code

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
import { linkData } from '../data'

export const NavBarContext = createContext(null)
console.log(NavBarContext)
export const NavBarProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <NavBarContext.Provider value={{ linkData }}>
     { children }
    </NavBarContext.Provider>
 )
}
```

This is my first time creating context
But there are a few errors which are giving me troubles:
"Unterminated regular expression literal."
"Cannot find namespace 'NavBarContext'."
"'>' expected."
"Cannot find name 'value'."
"Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'."
"No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'children'. Either declare one or provide an initializer."

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-rain-3es1ut?file=/context/NavBarContext.ts) with same code and erorrs.
Can someone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Why the file with this code and tsx markup in your sandbox has `.ts` extension instead of `.tsx`?

Comment: On online examples I saw only .js files, and i changed only to .ts, after i used .tsx it was working, that was a big mistake from my side :(